# Creating a package with several python files

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have a folder structure :

```
setup_seplot.py
seplot/
        __init__.py      (empty)
        seplot.py
        kw_dictionaries.py
```

In seplot.py, I have :

```
import kw_dictionaries as kd
```

If I run seplot.py, everything works well.

However, there is a problem when I use setup_seplot.py :

```
python setup_seplot.py sdist bdist_wheel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_seplot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from seplot import seplot as sep
  File "/home/XXXXX/code/Python-Tools/seplot/seplot.py", line 14, in <module>
    import kw_dictionaries as kd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kw_dictionaries'
```

This issue seems to come from the fact that in setup_seplot, I import seplot to get the version :

setup_seplot.py :

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from seplot import seplot as sep

version=sep.__VERSION__
setup(
     name='seplot',
     version=version,
     description="A front-end for Python PyX",
     install_requires=[ 'pyx', ],
     packages=find_packages(),
     scripts=['seplot/bin/seplot','seplot/seplot.py',
        'seplot/kw_dictionaries.py','seplot/style_dictionaries.py']
 )
```

If in seplot.py I replace

```
import kw_dictionaries as kd
```

by :

```
from . import kw_dictionaries as kd
```

Then the setup works fine, but the code (setup.py) doesn't.
I am quite lost here.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/3945375

Comment: Thanks, the solution was in there indeed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Keep your *scripts* and *packages* separated by using the *old-style* [`scripts` from *distutils*](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts). Or even better, use the [`console_scripts` *entry points* from *setuptools*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).
- Always use absolute imports in the executable scripts (if you have any).
- Use absolute or relative imports in the packages as you prefer (I believe absolute is better in the long run).
- In the setup script, don't import the packages from the project. Keep the version string in `setup.cfg` (or `setup.py`) and use [`importlib_metadata.version('ProjectName')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions) to read from within your actual code.

Comment: Thanks, but what would this look like in practice ???  

I tried keeping kw_dictionaries.py in a separate folder (inside `seplot/` ) but I ran into the exact same problem !

Comment: I guess the real problem with any organization is that I import a package from the project in the setup script. But I need this to pass the version to the setup file. What would be the clean way to pass the version otherwise ?

Comment: For the version string, use the suggestion 5 of : https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/ -- Even better, use `importlib_metadata.version('ProjectName') https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions

Comment: @SergeD still having difficulties with this or is the question answered?

Comment: I think it is solved, thank you ! I will test more with a more minimal (basically) project to make sure I fully get it.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was found in : [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/3945375) as suggested by [Gocht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3945375/gocht).

It feels hacky and I don't seem to understand why, but this works :

```
if __package__:
    import seplot.kw_dictionaries as kd
else:
    import kw_dictionaries as kd
```